# Convert HTML / Java encoded diactric signs from JSON message

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, json, encoding

I receive form API a JSON message which looks like:
{"message":"Nieprawid\u0142owy format"}

"\u0142" is polish charakter "ł". How can I convert the whole JSON message, as it may contain much more signs encoded this way? I have tried HTMLDecode, URLDecode and few others but none worked.

I try do to this with c# and asp.net. Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A JSON parser will take care of the conversion:

```
var json = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(str);
```

Comment: I will try this. However I am using json.net at the moment, not .net json classes. json.net might do same during deserialisation to business object, but I would like just to get the whole message as it is. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Is the json.net library another library than Newtonsoft? The class JsonConvert is from the Newtonsoft library: [http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/t_newtonsoft_json_jsonconvert.htm](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/t_newtonsoft_json_jsonconvert.htm)

Comment: Yes, I refer to Newtonsoft library,. Sorry for confusing. Given solution will try to deserialise into an object and get a value of "message". At the moment, I would like to have the whole message as it is, just properly encoded, so inteased of " {"message":"Nieprawid\u0142owy format"}" I need to have " {"message":"Nieprawidłowy format"}".

Comment: Finally, I gave up converting the whole JSON message. Deserializing it into my Business Object works perfect. Thanks.